# Send data from Android Activity to Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to send data from android activity to Xamarin form.

I have one content page, from where I am opening the android activity and passing the data from Xamarin app to Android activity. Now I need to send some data from Android activity to Xamaring Form on Finish activity.

**Xamarin Form:**

```
 var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(ScanActivity));           
 intent.PutExtra("Quantity", quantity);
 context.StartActivity(intent);
```

**Android Activity:**

```
private void DoneButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(?));
    myIntent.PutExtra("greeting", "Hello from the Second Activity!");
    SetResult(Result.Ok, myIntent);
    Finish();
}
```

I am creating the Intent before Finish button in android activity but what type of class should I use in Intent and in which event I will get the result of Intent.

Comment: I think  [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) can help you out.

Comment: Thank You. It's fixed my issue.